# What is Problem TypeError: action.value is undefined? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the file that I retrieved data from Firebase's table. I have no problem here. Here I have logged the console to see all the data. My problem is in the quiz.js file

**useQuestion.js**

```
import { getDatabase, ref, query, orderByKey, get } from "firebase/database";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useQuestions(yID) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // get data from database
    async function fetchQuestion() {
      const db = getDatabase();
      const questionRef = ref(db, "quiz/" + yID + "/questions");
      const questionQuery = query(questionRef, orderByKey());

      try {
        setError(false);
        setLoading(true);
        const snapshot = await get(questionQuery);
        setLoading(false);
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          setQuestions((prevQuestions) => {
            return [...prevQuestions, ...Object.values(snapshot.val())];
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(e);
        setError("You are Press Wrong Questions.");
      }
    }

    fetchQuestion();
  }, [yID]);
  return {
    loading,
    error,
    questions,
  };
}
```

The problem with this file is useReducer. I set the dispatch value but showing action.value is undefined. why this problem in my project.

**quiz.js**

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import useQuestions from "../../hooks/useQuestion";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import Answare from "../../answare";
import MiniPlayer from "../../miniPlayer";
import PogressBar from "../../pogressBar";
import _ from "lodash";

const initialState = null;
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "questions":
      action.value.forEach((question) => {
        question.options.forEach((option) => {
          option.checked = false;
        });
      });
      return action.value;
    case "answer":
      const questions = _.cloneDeep(state);
      questions[action.questionID].options[action.optionIndex].checked =
        action.value;

      return questions;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function Quiz() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [currentQuestions, setCurrentQuestions] = useState(0);
  const { loading, error, questions } = useQuestions(id);

  const [qna, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: "questions",
      value: questions,
    });
  }, [questions]);

  const handleAnswareChange = (e, index) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "answer",
      QuestionsID: currentQuestions,
      optionIndex: index,
      value: e.target.checked,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {loading && <div>Loading.....</div>}
      {error && <div>There was a problem.</div>}
      {!loading && !error && qna && qna.length > 0 && (
        <>
          <h1>{qna[currentQuestions].title}</h1>
          <h4>Question can have multiple answers</h4>
          <Answare
            options={qna[currentQuestions].options}
            handleChange={handleAnswareChange}
          />
          <PogressBar />
          <MiniPlayer />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Quiz;
```

Answer (score 0):

At my point of view you should console out `e.target.checked` before dispatching it. it may be undefined